# Change logo depending on menu item hover

Tags: css, html, menu, hover

I have an idea to make the main logo of my WordPress site change depending on which menu item a user hovers over.

The top part is as follows:
[DEFAULT LOGO] | [Menu item 1] [Menu item 2] [Menu item 3] [Menu item 4]

If X symbolizes the cursor, this would then happen:
[LOGO 2] | [Menu item 1] [Menu item 2 X] [Menu item 3] [Menu item 4]
- The user hovers over menu item number two and the logo changes accordingly. Usually I'd stay away from animations as they tend to get tacky, but in this instance I really want a [flip animation](http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) (sort of like a flip clock).

Menu item 1 loads logo 1 - item 2 loads logo 2, item 3 loads logo 3 - the rest of the menu items do nothing for the logo.

Is something like this possible? Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Looks like you can get some good ideas by adapting http://stackoverflow.com/q/4502633/4099598.

Comment: [tag:logo] is a programming language. Please don't use it's tag for questions relating to graphical logos.

Answer (score 0):

Yes..that's possible... but you need to trick the things....

Assume I was you... I would have done this in following steps..

- Create a simple page with your logo and menu items ( a normal HTML
  page)
- using jquery, I would update logo element by capituring menu
  mouseover event
- once, I will be done with that, I will try integrating it in
  wordpress...

using jquery, and registering a function for this in theme's `functions.php` would have done this part, I believe..